# Is there an archive of Andre Weil's papers?

Tags: mathematicians, weil

Most specifically I wonder if there is any chance that he kept the notebooks he refers to in his autobiography.  Probably he did not.  But Gauss kept his diary....

Answer (score 3):

Casey Westerman, archivist at the IAS in Princeton, advises that André Weil's papers are held at the Institut de France Académie des Sciences.

http://www.academie-sciences.fr/fr/Transmettre-les-connaissances/inventaires-des-fonds-d-archives-personnelles.html

In addition, the Bibliothèque nationale de France holds Simone Weil's papers including her correspondence with André.